# Start, stop and restart processes without resorting to batch files

Tags: windows, windows-xp, process

I need a GUI to start, stop, and restart processes (actually console applications).

Currently I start those console apps using BAT files. It's not convenient. Here is an example of BAT file which starts one process:

```
start srcds.exe -console -game swarm -port 25030 +map lobby -maxplayers 4 +exec server1.cfg +sm_basepath addons/sourcemod
```

Also I don't want the console window to be visible.

Comment: If running batch files in inconvenient, how do you expect it to be triggered otherwise that would be more convenient?  As for the visibility of the console during batch run, you can run it minimized by using a shortcut pointing at the batch file set to run it minimized, would that be sufficient?

Comment: I have 3 console servers. 3 console windows in my task bar. An application should have buttons: Start, Stop, Restart, and probably "Start All", "Kill All". I'm selecting a process, press Start.